# Question timestamp is incorrect in Google

Tags: discussion, google

I was doing a [search in Google](http://www.google.ca/#hl=en&q=visual+studio+running+custom+tool+commandline) about Visual Studio custom tools, and the second result pointed to a [question in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894806/run-a-visual-studio-custom-tool-at-build-time).

Google states that the article date is `21 May 2010`, but when viewing the question, the date is `May 21 '09` and nowhere on the page is an indication that the question was updated in 2010.

[image]

Is this a SO problem or a Google indexing misunderstanding? I don't know, but I though I'd share.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting. I have no idea where Google is getting that date; my guess is they are inferring it (incorrectly) from the page somehow.

I'm pretty sure no part of that page contains the date 21-May-2010 anywhere..

And since this is not our "bug", I am retagging this discussion.